# Ionic 2 app takes too much time to load even build with --prod flag

Tags: ionic2

Well, I am new to ionic 2 and build my first app having 2 pages and 2 services which are the very simple and for a news website.

The problem is, first I build my app for android using `--release` flag the file size was near 4MB and when I deploy on my mobile the load time was 14 - 17 seconds.

Then I search for 2 days to fix this issue and came up with the idea that I should enable production mode in `main.ts` and build using `--prod` flag . Now file size is 2.65MB and load time is 8 - 11 seconds which I think too much time for a mobile device. :(

My system information is:

```
 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

In my app I simply pulling news from rest server and displaying on my page. Am I doing something wrong or is there any issue with new version of ionic? I also read by some people that ionic 1 speed was good than the latest version.

**Note:** I run my app on 3 different devices the issue remain the same.

Comment: Open up your phone and look in the network what takes the most time to load. Which js file or css or whatever. Fix that. If you still can't figure out whats going on See lazy loading: http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/

Comment: @misha130 thanks for your comment. I have read about lazy loading. This is the good approach to speed up the boot time of app.

Comment: I have an app that is around 8mbs in size with maybe 20 pages and it has no lazy loading. It loads in maybe 3 - 5 seconds.

Comment: @misha130 wow its great. can you share how did you get that efficiency.  Actually I am new to ionic.

Comment: Can you share your code? Most likely you did something that is causing this delay. Can you try and create a brand new “blank app” and share what loading time that app has? If its fast then share your code if its same slow - environment etc

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml, and set SplashScreenDelay value to zero

`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>`.

Comment: Can you explain what will be the effect of this. setting splash screen delay time to zero?

Answer (score 0):

For me, below command worked:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs
```

You can use your own platform in above command instead of ios.
It decreased app load time in my case.
Please find more details here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-app-takes-too-long-to-start/97546